# issue while importing android project

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

I'm trying to import an Android project but i get this error : 
Cannot run program "": Launching failed

Error: Program "" not found in PATH

the project uses opencv which was referenced correctly , there was another sdk/java reference that i didn't understand , do you guys have any idea !

Comment: try to clean the project after importing it if all references correctly

Comment: still the same problem , here this project i'm trying to import https://github.com/h3ct0r/hand_finger_recognition_android/tree/master/hand-pose-estimation

Comment: are you import the OpenCv in your workspace ??

Comment: yes i did and it was imported fine , first i had problem with the opencv code but once imported there were no more errors still i don't know what's the problem

Comment: could you send me the error appear in error log ??

Comment: that's the problem , there is no error in the LogCat , but when i imported the project for the first time they were references for libraries : one for  opencv the other one was like this '../../sdk/java' i deleted both of them and added opencv

Comment: i have this in the console :
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop. but the application doesn't use native code , you can test the import if you wish here is the link : https://github.com/h3ct0r/hand_finger_recognition_android/tree/master/hand-pose-estimation

Comment: not LogCat , if you use eclipse open window -> show view -> error log
and you fill find the problem in more details  or 
window -> show views -> other -> general -> problem  see the problem for your project and post it

Comment: i found this : 
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.    and other warnings such as : Description Resource Path Location Type
Invalid project path: Include path not found (\home\h3ct0r\android-ndk-r8c\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to put NDK in your Environment Variable the problem it depend on NDK and can't find it try to configure it and post if you have error

take look how to add NDK to Eclipse

http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin

Comment: i already have the ndk r8 in the PATH variable , how can add it to eclipse because i can't find it in window->preferences->andoid

Comment: i post article about adding it in eclipse hope it useful for your case

Comment: thanks man , finally that red mark is gone , the .apk file was created but when i pass it to my phone for test it says that i must install opencv manager , but in other opencv application i didn't have to , i get this warning in the console : WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\ZouHair\Desktop\Android\workspace\hand-pose-estimation\bin\jarlist.cache

Comment: i think it problem in adt version  try to updated your version 
Help -> Check for Updates  , if you have updated version  so i think it  problem in files in this folder is read only  try each one suitable for you

Comment: Thanks mohammed , i downloaded the opencv manager on my phone and got it to work , i'll check for any possible updates , god bless you

Comment: May be this late , but i just want to understand why do i need to build the project with NDK if it doesn't have any Native code ?

Comment: OpenCV is coded with c so you can deal with it directly with java you need some languages low level that NDK support (c/c++) so you need it in your project